# Solubility of NaOH in Organic solvent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I am conducting organic reaction in Dimethoxyethane as solvent in the presence of base (NaOH), but the NaOH is not completely soluble ( Sparingly soluble) in Dimethoxyethane even after the addition of excess of solvent. Peoples says that for a reaction, the reactants must be completely soluble in solvent.

Can someone comments about solubility of Bases during organic reaction?

---

I actually want conduct similar kind of reaction, the paper mentioned that NaOH and organic compound stirred vigorously until to obtained clear solution. In my case my compound is completely soluble in DME but NaOH is poorly soluble.

[image]

Comment: I'd say it depends on the reaction you want to do. Can you tell what your reaction is?

Comment: @S.Chevalier please see my comment below.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to publish the procedure. Procedures from pier reviewed journals are generally reproducible (there are exceptions). So if they say "dissolve x grams in y mL" just do it.

NaOH is poorly soluble in dimethoxyethane. This might be sufficient if base is used as a catalyst or if reaction is slowly shifting to product.

Devil is in details. Heat, presence of water and other factors might impact soluility greatly.